# Parsing data from file of 3 columns to store data in dictionary with structure dict[key1][key2]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to solve the task:

1. Read data from the "Region", "Range" and "Population" columns.

> ```
> Region   Range   Population
> Region1   23       1299
> Region1   34        3400
> Region2   24        3200
> Region2   34        1209
> Region2   45        3008
> ```

2. Store the total population per range and region, such that the data_dict has the structure data_dict[region][range], where the values correspond to the population. For example, data_dict["Region1"]["23"] should contain the number of people that are 23 years old in the region "Region1".

I wanted to use nested dictionary like this

> `{‘Region1:{23:1299} ,’Region1’:{34:3400} ….}`

It allows to access to

```
data_dict[‘Region1’][ ‘34’] = 3400
```

The code:

```
with open(self.file_name, encoding='iso-8859-1') as file:
            reader = csv.DictReader(file)
            for line in reader:
                self.data_dict[line['Region']] = {line['Range']:line['Population']}
```

But it doesn’t work as expected because keys in the dictionary should be unique, when I add data from the file, it overwrites values and only the last one is accessible and it doesn’t put in the dictionary the very top data.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Dictionary doesn't support duplicate values it's expected behavior in python. You could use the list of tuples instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the key exists already. If it doesn't exist do what you are doing, otherwise add a key to the existing dictionary.

```
with open(self.file_name, encoding='iso-8859-1') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for line in reader:
        if line['Region'] in data_dict.keys():
            self.data_dict[line['Region']][line['Range']] = line['Population']
        else:
            self.data_dict[line['Region']] = {line['Range']:line['Population']}
```

The final data structure looks more like:

```
{
    "Region1": {
        "24": 1299,
        "34": 3400
    },
    "Region2": {
        "24": 3200,
        "34": 1209,
        "45": 3008
    }
}
```

but it allows access in the manner you describe `data_dict['Region']['Range']`.

Comment: Absolutely. Glad I could help!